# Can't boot Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 7 installed in Toshiba Portege laptop

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04, try to boot it using USB, I did download the .iso, I did put it into the USB. I'm using Toshiba Portege, forgot which one. When I'm open the BIOS with F2,

I can't boot it with USB, the laptop doesn't show the option to boot via USB. The laptop isn't old enough, I think it can boot via USB. but it doesn't show any option.

I know this is a stupid question. But, can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: not stupid at all. can you tell me the choices you see?

Answer (score 1):

i think that there are two options. one is f2 to open bios. the other one is f12 which is used to temporarily override the boot order. try plugging usb before starting your pc and then hitting f12(it might also be f8). see if it shows usb hdd in the options.

Comment: Yes. I tried again, plug my USB, hit the F12, I picked the "USB: Generic Flash Disk" option. And now it just showing one character underline (I forgot what it is) blinking. Is the installation always like that or it's a wrong step?

Comment: It didn't make it. Error occured. Is there any wrong step?

Comment: do you know how to use dd commands. that would be safe to use this. i am linking it here [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/441197/live-usb-stuck-at-syslinux/441229?noredirect=1#comment576661_441229)

Comment: I don't know and I don't understand. If the USB method doesn't work, should I use CD method or not?

Comment: your usb is not prepared properly. to boot from a pendrive, you need to prepare it. use unetbootin to prepare usb drive. i provided the link to you in which my previous comment which gives you an alternative to unetbootin. alternately, you can always use dvd directly.

Comment: sorry for the link, scroll up in the link and you will find an answer telling you to use dd command. dd command is a command used in ubuntu terminal (command prompt). it lets you to bluntly copy your iso to a pen drive so that you can boot from pen drive.

Comment: Unetbootin is just turn .iso file into USB right? I did that before with other software. I'll try with CD method first.

Comment: sometimes unetbootin does not work. then you use dd command. you open terminal(command prompt) and type "sudo dd if=path_to_iso of=path_to_device" and it would write it for you. the explanation is provided in the link

Answer (score 0):

Saw same problem on my Toshiba NB305.  Would not give the option to boot from a USB unless a recognized USB was currently in a USB port. Once there I could opt for the USB boot.  Then, of course, I had another issue.  But that's a different problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to follow this link;
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/bios-toshiba-portege-52656.html

It will show you how to enter BIOS on your laptop and then go through the menus
look for BOOT.

Under this BOOT tab, you show see a boot order. Here depending on the keys assigned to change, press them until you chose USB.

Save the settings by pressing F10 and accepting to save and exit.

Your laptop will automatically reboot, if your USB is still plugged in, it will boot into Ubuntu 12.04.

Good Luck :)